# Compare two values in a row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, pivot

```
select event_slots.id as event_slot_id, u.first_name, u.id AS user_id,

sum(case when next_round = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS yes,
sum(case when next_round = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS no

from event_slots

left join users as u on u.id = event_slots.selected_by_user_id 
left join audition_card_values as acv on acv.user_id = event_slots.selected_by_user_id 

where 
event_id = 1 and 
selected_by_user_id is not null

group by acv.user_id
```

Ergebnis:

[image]

Now i need only the first row "first_name" = "Eins" because "yes" equals "no".
How can i make this where statemant?
WHERE yes = no ... doesn't work.

Thanks for any help

Comment: ```... HAVING (`yes` = `no`)``` - output columns may be compared in HAVING clause only.

Comment: boy do you you need to blink a few times to read that one. `case when next_round = 1 then 1 else 0 end` is actually equivalent to `next_round = 1` because a boolean condition is 1 or 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would phrase the query as:

```
select 
    ev.id as event_slot_id, 
    u.first_name, 
    u.id AS user_id,
    sum(next_round = 1) AS yes,
    sum(next_round = 2) AS no
from event_slots as ev
inner join audition_card_values as acv 
    on acv.user_id = ev.selected_by_user_id 
left join users as u 
    on u.id = ev.selected_by_user_id 
where e.event_id = 1
group by ev.id, u.first_name, u.id
having sum(next_round = 1) = sum(next_round = 2)
```

Rationale:

- the conditional expressions in the `sum()` can be simplified
- you can use a `having` clause for filtering; MySQL also supports reusing aliases defined in the `select` clause in the `having` clause, so you could spell this: `having yes = no` - but I prefer repeating the  conditional expression, since this is standard SQL
- the `left join` on `audition_card_values` followed by a `where ... is not null` on the joining column can be rewritten as a simple `inner join`
- I fixed your `group by` clause; every non-aggregated column in the `select` clause must appear in the `group by` clause

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer!